# MySQL Event won't execute

Tags: mysql, events

Can anyone tell me why this event will not execute?

```
CREATE EVENT add_recurring
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
    STARTS '2015-04-17 06:01:00'
DO INSERT INTO payment (amount, note, custID, type) 
   SELECT amount, note, custID, 'C' FROM recurring WHERE day = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%e')
```

Here is what the recurring table looks like:

[image]

And here is the payment table which is not getting any of these values entered by the event:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error OR you are not getting desired result ?

Comment: No error. The Event is created and stored, however it is not entering any values into the payment table every minute, it is not entering anything at all.

Comment: you missed a **;** after the Insert query... You have written the select query immediately

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh The select is a nested query, it is an INSERT INTO SELECT, not and INSERT INTO and a SELECT.

Comment: @MySQLRockstar The recurring.day field is an integer, do I need some sort of cast to compare it to the DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%e')?

Comment: I suppose you've tested it with a starting date in the past ?

Comment: @Bartdude Yes, I have tested it with current dates and dates in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have changed your system clock? The query is 2 months from now...

Comment: I got so excited when I read this answer and went to change it, but then I realized it was a typo here and it is 2015-04-17 in my event :/

Comment: @NickSuwyn It doesn't sound like this answer solved your problem, but you accepted it as the correct answer? (the green tick indicates you accepted this answer). Questions with accepted answers are not likely to get any more attention. If you are yet to find an answer to your question, you should be able to un-accept this answer by clicking on the green tick again.

Answer (score 1):

Try these, assuming start date is future

1. try adding BEGIN , END and DELIMITER

   ```
   delimiter |

   CREATE EVENT add_recurring
     ON SCHEDULE
       EVERY 1 MINUTE
       STARTS '2015-04-17 06:01:00'
     DO
       BEGIN
         INSERT INTO payment (amount, note, custID, type), SELECT amount, note, custID, 'C' FROM recurring WHERE day = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%e')
     END |

   delimiter ;
   ```
2. Ensure that even schedular is turned on.

   `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`
   `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;`
   OR in my.cnf under  [mysqld] section `event_scheduler=ON`

Comment: I have done SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; and it still does not work.